# Deploying or publishing Alexa skills

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

It's my first few hours today to use Alexa so please bear with me for now.

I followed a tutorial that I found and was able to configure Alexa skills upto the Lamdba function. I was able to use the `Test` section inside Lamdba service and it worked really well. It can pull data from the external api. I was able to click the Listen button too.

However, I can't figure out how I will deploy this so that I can call the utterances using my real physical Alexa device. Not sure what to do next. And is it possible that I'll be the only one to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to publish it to use it on your physical alexa device.  As long as the alexa device is configured with the same Amazon account that you use to configure your skill then you can use the skill 'live' on your device.

In the configuration, I believe you must have progressed to the 'test' tab, but you don't need to fill in the publishing info to test the skill both virtually and on the device.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. I'll have to ask my daughter what account she used on the device. Thanks a lot! Now I'll need to figure out how to setup the account on the device. I'll try it today.Just an fyi, I have published it and submitted it for certification last night since I wasn't aware. If it gets certified and works, I've learned it too :)

Comment: You can also invite other amazon users to test. That way you don't need to have their account info.